# PySpark: Simulate SQL's UPDATE

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Spark DataFrames:

```
trg
+---+-----+---------+
|key|value|     flag|
+---+-----+---------+
|  1|  0.1|unchanged|
|  2|  0.2|unchanged|
|  3|  0.3|unchanged|
+---+-----+---------+
```

```
src
+---+-----+-------+-----+
|key|value|   flag|merge|
+---+-----+-------+-----+
|  1| 0.11|changed|    0|
|  2| 0.22|changed|    1|
|  3| 0.33|changed|    0|
+---+-----+-------+-----+
```

I need to "update" `trg.value` and `trg.flag` based on `src.merge` as described by the following SQL logic:

```
UPDATE trg
    INNER JOIN src ON trg.key = src.key
  SET trg.value = src.value,
      trg.flag = src.flag
  WHERE src.merge = 1;
```

Expected new `trg`:

```
+---+-----+---------+
|key|value|     flag|
+---+-----+---------+
|  1| 0.1 |unchanged|
|  2| 0.22|  changed|
|  3| 0.3 |unchanged|
+---+-----+---------+
```

I have tried using `when()`. It works for the `flag` field (since it can have only two values), but not for the `value` field, because I don't know how to pick the value from the corresponding row:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

trg = spark.createDataFrame(data=[('1', '0.1', 'unchanged'),
                                  ('2', '0.2', 'unchanged'),
                                  ('3', '0.3', 'unchanged')],
                            schema=['key', 'value', 'flag'])
src = spark.createDataFrame(data=[('1', '0.11', 'changed', '0'),
                                  ('2', '0.22', 'changed', '1'),
                                  ('3', '0.33', 'changed', '0')],
                            schema=['key', 'value', 'flag', 'merge'])

new_trg = (trg.alias('trg').join(src.alias('src'), on=['key'], how='inner')
          .select(
              'trg.*',
              when(src.merge == 1, 'changed').otherwise('unchanged').alias('flag'),
              when(src.merge == 1, ???).otherwise(???).alias('value')))
```

Is there any other, preferably idiomatic, way to translate that SQL logic to PySpark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
newdf = (trg.join(src, on=['key'], how='inner')
         .select(trg.key,
                 when( src.merge==1, src.value)
                 .otherwise(trg.value).alias('value'),
                 when( src.merge==1, src.flag)
                 .otherwise(trg.flag).alias('flag')))
```

```py
newdf.show()

+---+-----+---------+
|key|value|     flag|
+---+-----+---------+
|  1|  0.1|unchanged|
|  2| 0.22|  changed|
|  3|  0.3|unchanged|
+---+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Imports and Create datasets

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

l1 = [(1, 0.1, 'unchanged'), (2, 0.2, 'unchanged'), (3, 0.3, 'unchanged')]
dfl1 = spark.createDataFrame(l1).toDF('key', 'value', 'flag')
dfl1.show()
+---+-----+---------+
|key|value|     flag|
+---+-----+---------+
|  1|  0.1|unchanged|
|  2|  0.2|unchanged|
|  3|  0.3|unchanged|
+---+-----+---------+


l2 = [(1, 0.11, 'changed', 0), (2, 0.22, 'changed', 1), (3, 0.33, 'changed', 0)]
dfl2 = spark.createDataFrame(l2).toDF('key', 'value', 'flag', 'merge')
dfl2.show()
+---+-----+-------+-----+
|key|value|   flag|merge|
+---+-----+-------+-----+
|  1| 0.11|changed|    0|
|  2| 0.22|changed|    1|
|  3| 0.33|changed|    0|
+---+-----+-------+-----+
# filtering upfront for better performance in next join
# dfl2 = dfl2.where(dfl2['merge'] == 1)
```

Join datasets

```
join_cond = [dfl1['key'] == dfl2['key'], dfl2['merge'] == 1]
dfl12 = dfl1.join(dfl2, join_cond, 'left_outer')
dfl12.show()
+---+-----+---------+----+-----+-------+-----+
|key|value|     flag| key|value|   flag|merge|
+---+-----+---------+----+-----+-------+-----+
|  1|  0.1|unchanged|null| null|   null| null|
|  3|  0.3|unchanged|null| null|   null| null|
|  2|  0.2|unchanged|   2| 0.22|changed|    1|
+---+-----+---------+----+-----+-------+-----+
```

Use when function. If its null then use the original value or use new value

```
df = dfl12.withColumn('new_value', f.when(dfl2['value'].isNotNull(), dfl2['value']).otherwise(dfl1['value'])).\
    withColumn('new_flag', f.when(dfl2['flag'].isNotNull(), dfl2['flag']).otherwise(dfl1['flag']))

df.show()
+---+-----+---------+----+-----+-------+-----+---------+---------+
|key|value|     flag| key|value|   flag|merge|new_value| new_flag|
+---+-----+---------+----+-----+-------+-----+---------+---------+
|  1|  0.1|unchanged|null| null|   null| null|      0.1|unchanged|
|  3|  0.3|unchanged|null| null|   null| null|      0.3|unchanged|
|  2|  0.2|unchanged|   2| 0.22|changed|    1|     0.22|  changed|
+---+-----+---------+----+-----+-------+-----+---------+---------+

df.select(dfl1['key'], df['new_value'], df['new_flag']).show()
+---+---------+---------+
|key|new_value| new_flag|
+---+---------+---------+
|  1|      0.1|unchanged|
|  3|      0.3|unchanged|
|  2|     0.22|  changed|
+---+---------+---------+
```

This is for understanding, you can combine couple of steps into one.

Comment: I like the upfront filtering for optimization, thanks! Why is the filtering line commented out? You won't get `null` values after the join like this.

Comment: Sometime in question we just give dummy dataset and it’s not possible to filter upfront so kept as hint. If you have exact same situation like given dataset  then filtering before join would make lot difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()

data1 = [(1, 0.1, 'unchanged'), (2, 0.2,'unchanged'), (3, 0.3, 'unchanged')]
schema = ['key', 'value', 'flag']
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, schema=schema)
df1.show()

+---+-----+---------+
|key|value|     flag|
+---+-----+---------+
|  1|  0.1|unchanged|
|  2|  0.2|unchanged|
|  3|  0.3|unchanged|
+---+-----+---------+


data2 = [(1, 0.11, 'changed',0), (2, 0.22,'changed',1), (3, 0.33, 'changed',0)]
schema2 = ['key', 'value', 'flag', 'merge']
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, schema=schema2)
df2.show()

+---+-----+-------+-----+
|key|value|   flag|merge|
+---+-----+-------+-----+
|  1| 0.11|changed|    0|
|  2| 0.22|changed|    1|
|  3| 0.33|changed|    0|
+---+-----+-------+-----+

df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed("value", "value1").withColumnRenamed("flag", 'flag1')
mer = df1.join(df2, ['key'], 'inner')
mer = mer.withColumn("temp", when(mer.merge == 1, mer.value1).otherwise(mer.value))
mer = mer.withColumn("temp1", when(mer.merge == 1, 'changed').otherwise('unchanged'))
output = mer.select(mer.key, mer.temp.alias('value'), mer.temp1.alias('flag'))
output.orderBy(output.value.asc()).show()

+---+-----+---------+
|key|value|     flag|
+---+-----+---------+
|  1|  0.1|unchanged|
|  2| 0.22|  changed|
|  3|  0.3|unchanged|
+---+-----+---------+
```